# Customizing the hour value limit in Android Time Picker in 24 hour format

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am working on a functionality that require Android's default Time Picker widget in Spinner Mode with 24 hour format.

In existing android version, in 24 hour format, hour values varies from 0->23.  But the hour values need to vary from 0 to 24 and minute - 0 to 59, with minimum allowed values is 5 minutes.

Values allowed are 0:05 (5 minutes)to 24:00 (24 hours/ 1440 minutes)

How can I customize Android's TimePicker code to achieve this goal? 
Do I need to write a custom view for that?

Comment: You'll need a new `View`. But because of the open-source nature of Android it's quite easy to see [how TimePicker works](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TimePicker.java) and subclass it or to take the whole code and modify it to your needs. I think you'll need to have a look around [TimePickerSpinnerDelegate](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TimePickerSpinnerDelegate.java), there are some methods setting (hardcoded) minimum and maximum values there.

Comment: It all reduces to two `NumberPicker`s inflated from a resource. You can also use them directly in your layout.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I still have trouble in implementing the limit between 0:05 and 24:00.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to try and code this right now, but I'd say you will need to make a callback on the hour picker and dynamically update the range of the minute picker: whenever the hour picker reports that a 0 was selected, set the minimum to 5 and maximum to 59, when the hour is 24, set both minimum and maximum to 0, and for all other cases to 0–59. It would be a tiny bit easier if you were happy with the maximum being 23:59 because then you'd only have two cases and would only be changing the lower bound of the range.

Comment: NumberPicker has setOnValueChangedListener. It's called when value in the NumberPicker changes. From hour picker point of view functionality works fine, (1) When Hour is 24, showing '0' but disabling the minute picker as I don't want to show empty boxes and two other cases it work fine.

Comment: The problem comes from minute picker, when minute picker wraps around Min (0) to Max (59) or Max(59) to Min(0) value, the hourpicker value is decremented or incremented. So it goes out of range values like [24:59] from [0:05] instead of [24:00].

Comment: The decrement and increment of hour is completely up to you. In the second link I sent this is done between lines 117 and 137. Just drop them to not update hours at all or add your own logic which does not end with inconsistencies.